# Can't to rename save button label in Magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I'm trying to rename the save button in magento to submit [image]

using this code

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'item_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'countingstars';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_item';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('countingstars')->__('Submit'));

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('delete');
    }
```

but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it work, the _updateButton() should be place after the _construct(). So the code should look like this :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'item_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'countingstars';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_item';

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('delete');
$this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('countingstars')->__('Submit'));
    }
```